# xPath doesn't retrieve HTML as part of the content

Tags: php, xpath

I parse a web page with the help of xPath and retrieving the content of the div element, it omits HTML that is contained in that div element. How to make it retrieve the whole content of the div element with HTML included?

Comment: See my answer for a detailed explanation of the causes for such result. It will be best if you provide a specific XML document (as short as possible) and the specific XPath expression used -- then people would not have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
someExprSelectingtheDiv/node()
```

This selects all the children nodes (markup and text) of the `div`s selected in the first location step of the expression.

Do not work with the `string()` value of any selected element because this is only the concatenated (in document order) text descendants of this element.

Also, the string value of a node-set is the string value of the first node (in document order) of this node-set.

This information should be sufficient to explain the observed behavior in evaluating the problematic XPath expression.