# xPath doesn't retrieve HTML as part of what is needed

Tags: php, xpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [xPath doesn't retrieve HTML as part of the content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615205/xpath-doesnt-retrieve-html-as-part-of-the-content)

I parse a web page with the help of xPath and retrieving the content of the div element, it omits HTML that is contained in that div element. How to make it retrieve the whole content of the div element with HTML included?

Comment: Could you please provide some code example of what you are trying to do and what is going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [xPath doesn't retrieve HTML as part of the content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615205/xpath-doesnt-retrieve-html-as-part-of-the-content)

Voted to `CLOSE`

Comment: It seems we have a develop team asking the same question! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If this were in Javascript, I'd just say use the `.innerHTML` attribute, which would retrieve all the entirety of the contents of any given node. But since you're on PHP, there's no such function.

You can fake it, however, as detailed here: http://www.dynamit.us/blog/2009/03/php-dom-innerhtml-method/