# innerHTML in xPath?

Tags: php, xpath

Is there a way of retrieving HTML (and JavaScript) contained in a div element?

Comment: Is these threads related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615356/xpath-doesnt-retrieve-html-as-part-of-what-is-needed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615205/xpath-doesnt-retrieve-html-as-part-of-the-content

Comment: The answer could be yes, but there is no input sample and is a dup for other questions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a PHP developer but I found this:

```
function getNodeInnerHTML(DOMNode $oNode)
{
    $oDom = new DOMDocument();
    foreach($oNode->childNodes as $oChild)
    {
        $oDom->appendChild($oDom->importNode($oChild, true));
    }
    return $oDom->saveHTML();
}
```

from http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?p=4225203

I don't think you can select content including with only XPath, so a function like the one above may be necessary. And then you select your div like `//div[@id='someID']` etc.

Comment: Curious that this has been upvoted, and is 13 years old and no-one has pointed out the typo.  `childNode` on line 4 should be `childNodes`;

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml=new DOMDOCUMENT();
@$xml->loadHTML($htmlcontents);
$xpath=new DOMXPATH($xml);
$nodes=$xpath->query($xpath);

function getHtml($nodes) {
    $result = '';
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        $result .= $node->ownerDocument->saveHtml($node);
    }
return $result;
}
```

Source:
[how to get innerhtml by classname or id using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330566/how-to-get-innerhtml-by-classname-or-id-using-php)

Answer (score -1):

Now about:

//div[@id='your div']

If you don't care about performance?

Answer (score -1):

This will give you the outerHTML rather than the innerHTML, but you can easily strip the extra DIV tags at both ends.

Working example:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath( @DOMDocument::loadHTML($the_html_code) ) ;
$domElement = $xpath->evaluate("//div[@id='ID_of_the_div']")->item(0) ;
$outerHTML = $domElement->ownerDocument->saveXML($domElement) ;
```