# how to get innerhtml by classname or id using php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, dom

Hi i am loading content from external url. something like this.

```
$html=get_data($external_url);
```

where get_data() is a function for getting content using curl.

now after this , i want to get the inner html from different html elements like h1,div,p,span by using their class  or id.

for example
if the content from external url($html) is something like this.

```
<html>
<title></title>
<body>
    <h1 class="title">I am title</h1>
    <div id="content">
        i am the content.
    </div>
</body>
```

now i want to get the inner html of a html tag with class="title". similarly i want to get inner html of a tag with id="content"

How to do this using php? i have no knowledge about DOM, XML. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function `DOMDocument::saveHTML()`. In the current php versions, this can take a node you want to save as html. To save the inner html of a node, you have to save each child node.

```
function getHtml($nodes) {
  $result = '';
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $result .= $node->ownerDocument->saveHtml($node);
  }
  return $result;
}
```

To fetch the nodes, you can use Xpath. The id is easy.

Fetch all element nodes:

`//*`

that have the id attribute "content"

`//*[@id="content"]`

Use only the first found node, in case somebody added the same id multiple times.

`//*[@id="content"][1]`

Get the child nodes - node() includes element, text and several other nodes

`//*[@id="content"][1]/node()`

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

echo getHtml($xpath->evaluate('//*[@id="content"][1]/node()'));
```

The class attribute is a little more complex. Class attributes are token lists, they can contain several class names. Here is a trick to matching them. The Xpath function normalize-space() converts all groups of whitespaces into single space separators. Add a space in front and to the end and you get a string like `" one two three "`. Now you can check if `" one "` is a part of that string. In Xpath:

Normalize the class attribute:

`normalize-space(@class)`

Add spaces to start and end:

`concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " ")`

Check if it contains the substring

`contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " title ")`

Use it to limit the nodes

`//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " title ")][1]/node()`

Put together:

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<html>
<title></title>
<body>
    <h1 class="title">I am title</h1>
    <div id="content">
        i am the <b>content</b>.
    </div>
</body>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

function getHtml($nodes) {
  $result = '';
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $result .= $node->ownerDocument->saveHtml($node);
  }
  return $result;
}

// first node with the id
var_dump(
  getHtml(
    $xpath->evaluate('//*[@id="content"][1]/node()')
  )
);

// first node with the class
var_dump(
  getHtml(
    $xpath->evaluate(
      '//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " title ")][1]/node()'
    )
  )
);

// alternative - handling multiple nodes with the same class in a loop
$nodes = $xpath->evaluate(
  '//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " title ")]'
);
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  var_dump(getHtml($xpath->evaluate('node()', $node)));
}
```

Output: https://eval.in/118248

```
string(40) "
        i am the <b>content</b>.
    "
string(10) "I am title"
string(10) "I am title"
```

Comment: thank you soo much. as a beginner to be able to do all this wher should i start learning and what all i should learn. i have no knowledge of dom, xml, xpath. can u pls give a basic introduction if u don't mind?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy. Try

```
$dom_doc = new DomDocument();
$dom_doc->loadHTML($returned_external_html);
$element = $dom_doc->getElementsByTagName('table'); // you can search for any tags like <img>, <p> and etc. This will return a DOMNodeList
$element = $dom_doc->getElementById('specific_id'); // If you know the id of element you are seeking for try this. This will return a DOMElement
//If I want to getINNERHTML for the table element, the code should be:
$innerHTML= ''; 
$children = $element->childNodes; 
foreach ($children as $child) { 
    $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child ); 
}
echo $innerHTML; //contain the inner html of the element
```

Check these links for more help
[DOMDocument GetElementsByTagName](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) 
[DOMDocument GetElementById](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php)

Comment: Thank you.
but how do i get the innerhtml? i tried as u said. but i was getting errors as method not found for getElementByID('content'), gelElementByClassName('title');

Comment: Easily, you can use `$dom_doc->saveXML($element);` which will return the inner content of a DOM element as string plus the node itself. I updated my solution and hopefully it will help you